# Microsoft Graph API - Hidden Channels when creating a Team

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using HTTP Client to make requests to the Graph API in order to create a Team with multiple channels, everything is created correctly however the channels show up as "hidden".

I've already tried using the "isFavoriteByDefault" property on the channels but to no effect.

I got it to work by creating the team without channels and then creating each channel individually but this is too slow.

How can I create the Team and all the Channels in one request but have them visible?

My Code:

```
HttpClient client = Client("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams", token);

var data = new
{
    odataTemplateProperty = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
    visibility = "Private",
    displayName = Team.Name,
    description = Team.Description,
    channels = Channels.Select(x => new
    {
        odataProperty = "#Microsoft.Teams.Core.channel",
        membershipType = "private",
        isFavoriteByDefault = true,
        displayName = x.Name,
        description = x.Description
    }).ToList()
};

string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data).Replace("odataProperty", "@odata.type").Replace("odataTemplateProperty", "template@odata.bind");

StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = Post(client, content).Result;
```

Comment: This seems only to work for private channels, and when you made them one by one. You can set IsFavoriteByDefault if you create the team from a custom template, but this doesn't seem to work very well.